# Using clang-tidy to check c++17 code

Tags: c++, c++17, clang-tidy

I installed clang-tidy on Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt install clang-tidy
```

I ran it on a simple C++ 17 file, and got a warning and errors:

```
/home/erelsgl/Dropbox/ariel/CPLUSPLUS/intro/01-single-file/ptr.cpp:17:3: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [clang-diagnostic-c++11-extensions]
                auto i = make_unique<int>();
                ^
/home/erelsgl/Dropbox/ariel/CPLUSPLUS/intro/01-single-file/ptr.cpp:17:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'make_unique' [clang-diagnostic-error]
                auto i = make_unique<int>();
```

How can I tell clang-tidy to check this file according to c++17 standards?

NOTE: To build the program, I run:

```
clang++-5.0 --std=c++17 ptr.cpp
```

Comment: Try -std=c++17 perhaps. If no worko, try  -std=c++1z.

Comment: Did you read the [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depending on your compiler / clang-tidy version, the default C++ standard version used to compile source files may vary. clang's default std version is `gnu++-98` (or `gnu++-14` starting with clang 6.0), and typically clang-tidy has the same defaults as clang.

I'm guessing that `-std=c++17` (or `-std=c++1z`) isn't specified in the C++ compiler flags, used for compiling `ptr.cpp`, so clang-tidy falls back to the default `-std=gnu++98`, and therefore gives warnings for C++11 code.

For asking clang-tidy to handle C++17, you should specify the `-std` flag as suggested by @n.m., as parameter to the `-extra-arg` option, for example:

`clang-tidy -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg=-std=c++17`

**Edit:**

Since `clang++-5.0` is used for compiling `ptr.cpp`, it may be a good idea to use the matching clang-tidy version, 5.0 (on Ubuntu 16.04, the default clang-tidy version installed through apt is 3.8), that is:

`clang-tidy-5.0 -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg=-std=c++17`

If not already installed, you could grab it from:
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/xenial/main/base/clang-tidy-5.0

Comment: I tried 'clang-tidy -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg="--std=c++17"' and  tried 'clang-tidy -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg="--std=c++1z"' and  tried 'clang-tidy -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg=c++17' and  tried 'clang-tidy -p . ptr.cpp -extra-arg=c++1z', but I still get a lot of errors. For example, I get: "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.1.0/../../../../include/c++/7.1.0/type_traits:177:5: error: 'inline' can only appear on functions [clang-diagnostic-error]".

Comment: Note: to build the program, I run "clang++-5.0 --std=c++17 ptr.cpp". It runs without errors. Maybe clang-tidy does not find clang++-5.0?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi If you're using clang++-5.0, it's probably good to use clang-tidy-5.0 - I would suggest to run `clang-tidy-5.0` explicitly (the default clang-tidy for Ubuntu 16.04 is `3.8`, so it may be the one that's picked). Generally clang and clang-tidy are independent of each other (although they share some libraries).

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi You could pick clang-tidy-5.0 from here: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/xorg-edgers/xenial/main/base/clang-tidy-5.0

Comment: This solved the problem! I use: '''clang-tidy-5.0 -extra-arg="--std=c++17" ptr.cpp'''

Comment: I think the extra-arg should be "--std=c++17" and not "c++1z"

Comment: `--extra-arg="-std=c++17"` worked for me